# Python / Flask / WTForm / Jinja: Passing variable value into wftform field for "Update Page"

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I save `FlightNo`, `Terminal` and `Status` into MongoDB. I want to create an update page, so the values can get updated. How can I pass the existing values from the Database within the WTForm field?

`app.py`:

```
# Document just for your info!
Document = { "_id" : ObjectId("5bfffb603129d742ac94b990"), "flightno" : "LH-100", "terminal" : "A1", "status" : "Inbound" }

@app.route("/update/<id>"):
def update(id):
     currFlight = db.find_one({"flightno": id})
     form = FlightForm()

     if request.method == "POST":
        f = session["flightno"] = form.flightno.data
        t = session["terminal"] = form.terminal.data
        s = session["status"] = form.status.data

        query = {"flightno": f}
        update = {"$set": {"flightno": f, "terminal": t, "status": s}}
        db.update(query, update)

        return redirect(url_for("index"))
     return render_template("update.html", currFlight=currFlight)
```

`update.html`:

```
<form method="POST">
   {{form.hidden_tag()}}
   {{form.flightno.label}} {{form.flightno}} <br>
   {{form.terminal.label}} {{form.terminal}} <br>
   {{form.status.label}} {{form.status}} <br>
   {{form.submit()}}
</form>
```

How can I pass the values from `currFlight` into the form, so the fields are already filled with the values from `currFlight`?
I tried `value=""`, although it just worked with the `StringField`. `Terminal` and `Status` are `SelectFields`, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When form method is 'POST', you are reading the values from the form fields and saving them in the database. In similar way, when the form method is GET, you can read values from the database and pass them to the form. See code below -

```
#after your if block
elif request.method == "GET":
    form.flightno.data = currFlight.flightno
    form.terminal.data = currFlight.terminal
    form.status.data = currFlight.status
```

When the page loads first time, method will be GET, and forms fields will have values from the database. Make sure to pass form to the html template as below -

```
return render_template("update.html", currFlight=currFlight, form=form)
```